# How render fusionchart using my javascript function

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I want to render/call fusion chart from my javascript function.

For example:- Currently we need to do these to show chart:-

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

      var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Column3D", "myChartId", "400", "300" );
      myChart.setXMLUrl("Data.xml");
      myChart.render("chartContainer"); 
    // --> 
    </script>
```

But I want to write a function to render it something like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

      var column3d = new MyChart.Column.YFColumn3D("MSColumn3D", "MSColumn3DChart", "1100", "300");
      column3d.setXMLUrl("Data.xml");
      column3d.render("chartContainer"); 
    // --> 
    </script>
```

Here YFColumn3D can be a function that render actual function of fusion chart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on what is your requirement? From your question, it seems you want to do `var MyChart = {Column: {YFColumn3D: FusionCharts}};`!! But that sure is not what I think you actually want. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just want to call "var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Column3D", "myChartId", "400", "300" );" from my custom function like "var column3d = new MyChart.Column.YFColumn3D("MSColumn3D", "MSColumn3DChart", "1100", "300");" and YFColumn3D can be function that contains "new FusionCharts(..." function.

Comment: Its some thing like abstract fusionchart function into my function.

Comment: Then simply assign `FusionCharts` to the variable in your object and use it.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in the discussion under the question, I derive that you want separate functions based on the chart type. One cool way to do that would be create wrapper functions around `FusionCharts` to do the same.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Assuming that MyCharts is the object to which you want to
// add type based abstractions.
var MyCharts = {};

(function (requiredChartTypes, objectToExtend) {
    for (var chartType in requiredChartTypes) {
        objectToExtend[chartType] = (function (chartType) {
            return function (id, width, height) { // add more args if needed
                new FusionCharts({
                    type: chartType,
                    width: width,
                    height: height
                });
            };
        }(chartType));
    }
}({
    column3d: true,
    column2d: true
    pie2d: true
}, MyCharts));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Now anywhere you can use as follows
var newChart = MyCharts.column3d("myChartId", "1100", "300");
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not exactly sure if this solves your requirements, still I will try and explain how I made it to work. In case your question is different, I would request you to rephrase or elaborate. Better the question, better is the solution. ;-)

1. I first took two arguments within an anonymous function defined right after including `FusionCharts.js`. The first argument is the list of chart types I intend to use in my function and second is the object to which I want to lend individual functions mapped to each chart type.
2. Then I iterated over the list of required chart types and added functions to my object that I want to extend for each property in that object. These functions accept only `id`, `width` and `height`.
3. The function per chart type is put under a closure to retain the chart type.
4. The function per chart, when called, is made to return a new instance of FusionCharts with the specific chart type and other arguments.